# cannot use android in build gradle app level with dsl Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dsl

I was learn about dsl-kotlin and I want migrate my dependencies app from groovy to dsl-kotlin, but I'm alwasy got `Unresolved reference: android`

```
plugins {
id(Build.library)
kotlin(Build.kotlinAndroid)
kotlin(Build.kotlinAndroidExtensions)
kotlin(Build.kotlinKapt)
}

android{} << here always got 'Unresolved reference: android'

dependencies {
}
```

maybe someone have ideo for this probelem. Thanks.